# R Markdown knit to pdf file not found

Tags: r, r-markdown

I tried to knit to pdf when an errormessage that said I had to update tinytex appeared, which i did. Then the message below showed up. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling tinytex several times. I even tried installing and using miketex, that wouldn't work either. Can someone help me out please. I am very desperate my deadline is in a few hours.

```
processing file: Uebung-9.Rmd
  |.......                                                               |  10%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..............                                                        |  20%
label: 4)a)
  |.....................                                                 |  30%
label: 4)b
  |............................                                          |  40%
label: 4)b)
  |...................................                                   |  50%
label: 4)c)
  |..........................................                            |  60%
label: 4)d)
  |.................................................                     |  70%
label: 4)d 20
  |........................................................              |  80%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...............................................................       |  90%
label: 4)d
  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: Uebung-9.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Uebung-9.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Uebung-9.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\Karthika\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\Karthika\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
! LaTeX Error: File `Uebung-9_files/figure-latex/4' not found.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Uebung-9.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Uebung-9.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Comment: Latex error  Check your configuration (OS & Latex versions?) You do have Tex installed, right?

Comment: It seems a figure is not found. Are figures included? If yes, are they referenced correctly. In case provide a reproduible example.